# jQuery regex tag wrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i have a contenteditable div where i want to make it so that when a user types in a hashtag, everything between that hashtag and the next space will be wrapped in

```
<span class="tag"></span>
```

for example, if a user types in "hi, my name is john #sweaters are a cool article of clothing" the html would read

```
 hi my name is <span class="tag">#john</span> are a cool article of clothing
```

so far i've got this in my javascript but i think don't know where to go from here

```
$('.post_box').keydown(function(){
    var note = $(this).html();
    var hashtagPattern = /[#]/i;
    var spacePattern = /[ ]/i;
        // find hashtag
        // find space
        // get stuff between them
        var tag = stuff between them;
        tag.wrap('<span class=\"tag\" contenteditable=\"false\"/>');
 });
```

Comment: Why does the hashtag move from "sweater" to "john"?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get what you mean, although I can't understand why you disappeared "sweater" and placed the hashtag to "john", but, suppose that you have this:

```
hi my name is john are a cool article of clothing
```

and someone adds a hashtag on "john" like this:

```
hi my name is #john are a cool article of clothing
```

the html should be something like this:

```
hi my name is <span class="tag">#john</span> are a cool article of clothing
```

I made a modification to your script

```
$('.post_box').keyup(function(){
var note = $(this).html(), pattern = /\s\#[A-Za-z0-9]+\s/gi, tag;
while(tag = pattern.exec(note)){
note = note.replace(tag.toString(),' <span class=\"tag\" contenteditable=\"false\">'+$.trim(tag.toString())+'</span> ');
}
$(this).html("");
$(this).html(note);
});​
```

if you notice this line:

```
note = note.replace(tag.toString(),' <span class=\"tag\" contenteditable=\"false\">'+$.trim(tag.toString())+'</span> ');
```

you'll realize that is wrapping the hashtag between the , of course there is still a lot of thing to do in order to make this code something usable (at least that's what I think), but that is entirely up to you.

you can find the test code here [TEST](http://jsfiddle.net/miguelacho/vRhyu/)